# Javascript cannot use in operator to search for length in

Tags: javascript, flask, web

I get the error when clicking in the datatable search bar and typing anything followed by backspace. Not sure why I'm getting this error but some help and explanation would be awesome and very appreciated. Here's the relevant code below with exact error message. Also the lines it says the error comes from are wrong since flask doesn't create proper error messages

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in 
    at s (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.map (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Na (jquery.dataTables.min.js:40)
    at ub (jquery.dataTables.min.js:39)
    at ca (jquery.dataTables.min.js:38)
    at L (jquery.dataTables.min.js:27)
    at ra (jquery.dataTables.min.js:44)
    at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.min.js:91)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
```

```
const sendRequest = (elName) => {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/?????",
    contentType: "application/json",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(elName),
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(res) {},
  });
};

const pullValues = () => {
  processName = JSON.stringify('');
  creationTime = JSON.stringify('');
  finishTime = JSON.stringify('');
  return processName, creationTime, finishTime;
}

const createButtons_Table = function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/?????",
    contentType: "application/json",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'JSON'
  }).done(function(response) {
    result = response;
    resultLen = result.length - 1;
    for (let i = 0; i < resultLen; i++) {
      btnElements.innerHTML += `<button class='button-machines' name=${result[i]} id='button-${i}'>${result[i]}</button>`;
      for (let x = 0; x < resultLen; x++) {
        let buttons = $(`#button-${x}`);
        buttons.click(function() {
          btnNames = document.getElementById(`button-${x}`).name;
          machineTableEl = $("#machine-table");
          tableBody = document.getElementById("machine-info-body");
          tableBody.innerHTML = `
                                    <tr><td>${x}</td>
                                        <td>${btnNames}</td>
                                        <td>FILLERINFO</td>
                                        <td>FILLER</td>
                                        <td>FILLER</td>
                                    </tr>`;
          sendRequest(btnNames);
          machineTableEl.removeAttr("style");
          $('#approved-software-list-right').removeClass('hidden');
        });
      }
    }
  });
  $('#machine-table').DataTable();
}
```

Comment: Why do you have two loops that are iterating from 0 to resultlen?

Comment: @Barmar I realize it's not needed at all but I'll change it eventually when I clean up the code more, I just cant seem to figure out why its throwing that error though

Comment: It seems like a problem, because you're adding multiple event handlers to each `#button-${x}`.

Comment: The problem seems to be related to your dataTable options.

Comment: I'm just not too sure what would be causing it. If I move the click event out of the for loop then it obviously only will register the last button thats dynamically generated. It works fine right now even with both for loops but the issue is when I click in the search bar for datatable and type anything, anytime I press the delete key after that it throws the error I posted. I just don't know what could be causing that since I didn't configure or change any settings for the table